# Android play store: give access to paid app version from free app without any charge

Tags: java, android, xamarin.android, google-play

I have two apps:

- A paid app that costs $0.99 (without ads)
- A free app - without ads

In free version I have share page and if user shares the app 10 times they should be able to get pro (paid) version for free.

I can't figure out how to make this available on google play store.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you trying to figure out how to add an app to the play store? Your question/problem doesn't really follow your premise.

Comment: Maybe you can use Promo Codes, but you have a quantity limit per quarter.

Read this:
https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2016/01/create-promo-codes-for-your-apps-and-in.html

Comment: you should do it manually, without google play as only you decide which version is accesible by user. just call same code as when you check if the version is paid

Comment: What is the difference between free & paid app. Only ad?

Comment: @RajeshRajaram unfortunately no. Paid app has notifications as additional feature

Comment: Please see [Why we're not customer service for your favorite company](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company)